# Listbox is not displayed properly in Chrome

Tags: html, css

Hi I am trying to add some background color and border to the Listbox and it is showing some white strip at the right and bottom of the options. When I hover on each item then they are rearranged properly.

```
  <select>
     <option>Hello</option>
     <option>World</option>
  </select>​
```

And the CSS is

```
  select {
    background: Red;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: white;
    width: 100px;  
  }
  select option{
    margin : 0   
  }

  select:active {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#666, white);
  }
```

Please see it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CUA9p/524/). ​I can see white strip at the right of each option and bottom of all options. How to get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `option{background:red}`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CUA9p/525/)**